# Document Fragment

Tags: javascript, dom

In mdn documentation is see about the document Fragment and look like there is two way to make document Fragment, first way is used the documentFragment constructor or the second way is use the createdocumentfragment( )

What is the different between this 2 way ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment#usage_notes: _"An empty DocumentFragment can be created using the document.createDocumentFragment() method or the constructor."_ - the constructor does not take any additional parameters either, so I would say we can assume that both do the same thing.